# Указать путь к файлу

Tags: php, javascript, файлы, path

Итак, есть `json` файл, в котором хранятся какие-то данные. Файл `php` берет данные из файла `json`, и файл `js` делает тоже самое. Как указать путь к этому файлу?

Вот так вот выглядит структура файлов в проекте. Никак не могу понять как указать путь.(Квадраты это папки, овалы это файлы, красная линия это в каких файлах будет указан путь к `json`).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно так, если файл лежит в корне: `../../file.json`. [Различие между абсолютными и относительными путями](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths)

Comment: @slippyk Нет, так не работает. Я просто не понимаю, если у меня в localhost папка проекта, в ней еще три папки, в каждой по файлу. И если мне нужно указать путь к файлу `json` в другом файле который находится в другой папке то по сути нужно выйти  в localhost, потом зайти в папку проекта, потом в  папку с файлом `json` и указать сам файл, верно?

Comment: Какой из этих каталогов является корнем сайта (DocumentRoot)? Где вам нужно использовать путь к файлу? 
Если корень сайта установлен в Project, то при переходе на localhost/Php/Some.php внутри этого Some.php путь к файлу будет "../Data/Data.json", а в файле Some.js путь можно описать как "/Data/Data.json"

Comment: @therainycat Корень сайта установлен в localhost. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Тогда ../../Project/Data/Data.json и /Project/Data/Data.json. Но я бы посоветовал пересмотреть структуру проекта и не использовать символы в большом регистре.

Comment: В php файле - `../Data/Data.json`, в js файле `http://localhost/Project/Data/Data.json`.

Comment: @Visman Указал как вы написали. Путь вроде как верный НО, в `php`  в этот файл у меня идет запись данных в `json` (и все нормально работает), а вот в `js` с беру содержимое и вывожу на  экран(но этого не происходит). Вывод на экран работает 100%, ибо я пробовал помещать `json`  в файл к `js` и все работало. Скажите, почему может так быть?Если вам не будет тяжело, могу скинуть ссылку проекта на github.

Comment: А вы в браузере в консоль и во вкладку "сеть" посмотрите куда идет запрос из js, чтобы получить json и какая ошибка при этом.

Comment: @Visman Пишет что запрос вообще не отправляется.